# How to order query results with multiple datetime?

Tags: php

I do want to sort my results from different datetimes, like this `("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datetime_1 and datetime_2 and datetime3 DESC");`

is that possible ??

Comment: Maybe `order by datecolumn desc`.. is your date column an actual date column? Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html.

Comment: my field is datetime ? is it ok ?

Comment: Yea, what happens? What framework are you using or did you write those functions?

Comment: only the current user appears

Comment: How do you get your posts? from results()?

Comment: i use echo then it will show all the users

Comment: you just sort within sql query like this SELECT * FROM users ORDER By your_date DESC

Comment: @jothi i tried that but, only 1 user is appeared, and what's more the current user only appeared

Comment: ORDER BY column_name ASC  or ORDER BY column_name DESC @phew

Comment: what if 3 dates I want to sort ? ex. date_1 date_2 date_3, is it possible ? Like, ORDER BY date_1 and date_2 and date_3 DESC ??

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL to get your posts, you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_posts_table ORDER BY your_date_field DESC
```

In some situations, you may just add

```
ORDER BY your_date_field DESC
```

after your SQL.

if you using ORM, you have to look at the document.

Comment: only one of the posts appeared

Answer (score 0):

your overwriting  **while($users->results() as $users) {**  $users variable

so you have to do something like this

```
while($users->results() as $users_data) { 

echo $user_data->name;

 }
```